# Php Pagination Help ( Maintaining/ Passing Variables Like Sql Query) to different pages

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pagination

```
$sql2 = ("SELECT emp_no,first_name,last_name,gender,hire_date,birth_date FROM employees WHERE first_name or last_name LIKE '%$Search%' $limit");

$sql22 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1"){

if ($_GET['$pn'] < 1) { 
    $pn = 1; // force if to be 1
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
    $pn = $lastPage; 
}

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;


if ($_GET['$pn'] == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $_GET['$pn']. '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}


else if ($_GET['$pn'] == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $_GET['$pn'] . '</span> &nbsp;';
}

else if ($_GET['$pn'] > 2 && $_GET['$pn'] < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $_GET['$pn'] . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';


$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

if ($pn != $lastPage) {
    $nextPage = $pn + 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
```

When clicking the NEXT button  PHP_SELF is called in order to load the next 10 results to be loaded on the page, but instead when NEXT is clicked it clears the past query and selects * from database

Comment: Try to set at the$paginationDisplay the additional parameters of the query.

Comment: First post had a lot of edit errors, this is more clear

Comment: thanks for your answer. Am i doing this through $SESSION,

Comment: Can you post some more code?

Comment: I am New to this Hopefully this helps.

Comment: any suggestions guys????